# Windows 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Servrices Server how to set up separate virtual circuit per user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, samba, terminal-services

Terminal Server relies on the underlying Windows operating system to establish the transport for the client pool, and Windows will only issue one TCP/IP connection to the remote server – in this case Samba. This results in all virtual client sessions and share mounts being multiplexed over a single TCP/IP transport pipe to the Samba server

On a `Windows Server 2008 R2 RDS Server` I'm trying to maintain a separate `TCP` virtual circuit per each user - this for allow separate connections to a remote `Samba` shares per each user.

On old Windows server, you can allow each terminal server client to maintain a separate virtual circuit using `regedt32`, navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Rdr\Parameters` and adding a value named `MultipleUsersOnConnection` as a type `REG_DWORD` entry and setting the data value to 0.

I can't find the same registry setting for Windows Server 2008 R2 with RDS rolde installed.

**How I can maintain a separate `TCP` virtual circuit per each user ?**

Answer (score 0):

Probably you shoud state a little bit more clearly what problem you are trying to solve, it seems to me that your users connected to RDS having an issue with connecting to Samba shares from RDS session. If this is the case look at (probably) relevant question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/95872/sambawindows-allow-multiple-connections-by-different-users).